# Can't connect to archieve

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and i already having some problems.
When I try to, for example, download joe(sudo apt install joe), I just get this:
`0% [Connecting to ro.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]` and it is not responding.This is the case in every other installation. 
 I have stable internet connection (around 280mb dowload speed and 250 upload speed. Using wired connection.).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73845/discussion-on-question-by-sinka-attila-cant-connect-to-archieve).

Answer (score 0):

Search (on your system) for the 'Software & Updates' control panel. Choose a different mirror from the 'Ubuntu Software' tab.
Run sudo apt update. Then try installing joe again